# Ansible fetch module issue with destination directory

Tags: ansible

When I am using the fetch module of ansible it always first create temp directories under the root folder with the structure of hostname/tmp/ and then copies the file

I have tried with several options but couldn't find a workaround to directly copy in a particular directory via bypassing the temp folders creationg

Is there any workaround to it

```
# Store file into /tmp/fetched/host.example.com/tmp/somefile
- fetch:
    src: /tmp/somefile
    dest: /tmp/fetched

# Specifying a path directly
- fetch:
    src: /tmp/somefile
    dest: /tmp/prefix-{{ inventory_hostname }}
    flat: yes
```

Comment: Hi,

Did you try adding a "/" at the end of your "dest" when "flat: yes"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [*synchronize*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html) module

```yaml
- synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: /tmp/somefile
    dest: /tmp/fetched
```